# Any reason why Fortran is outputting some strange numbers for Project Euler 57?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

learned python in the beginning of the summer, need to switch to Fortran for lab work. Could someone please help me discern why Fortran is outputting such odd numbers when doing simple addition? The photo below should be a good explanation of what I am trying to do with the program.

[Fortran vs Python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55f7k.png)

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question; don't link to an external image.

Comment: Have you heard of integer (and floating point) bounds and overflow?

Comment: @Evert Sorry I assumed the photo would provide more information about my problem than direct code. I am aware of overflow although the very first result of 3 + 2 should result in 5. I do not believe that 5 should result in an overflow error.

Comment: You can also include output (probably formatted in a code block) in your question. Links go away, images can't be read by anyone and are at times harder to read (I can increase the font size, but that won't help an image). Why do you think an image provides more information than the actual code?

Comment: @Evert Idk, this is my first post here. That's an excellent recommendation for the future however, and will be sure to keep that in mind. After some more tests with the code and different ranges/int&real kinds it seems that Fortran is not able to go past 100 iterations on int&real kind r=18. Does that mean there is no way to run this type of program in Fortran? Is there some extension for bigger integers or is it a drawback of the language?

Comment: 1/ You can [edit] your question to include the actual code and output. 2/ you can amend your question with the new information, and with your new, actual question (which you have now asked only in your comment).

Answer (score 1):

From [Python's floating-point tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

> almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 "double precision"

which in Fortran terms is a `double precision` or `real(kind=REAL64)` variable. Note that Python is *weakly typed*; you can stuff pretty much whatever you want into a Python variable and it just sort of knows what to do with it. Fortran is *strongly typed* so if you want your floating point data stored as REAL32, REAL64, or REAL128 (whatever your compiler defines in the `ISO_Fortran_env` module), you have to explicitly tell Fortran which specific type of float you want. By default, Fortran reals are REAL32 (so-called 'single precision') so you shouldn't be surprised that the results don't match what Python is generating.

That, of course, presumes you know the **Secret Mystery Knowledge** of the default numerical precision of both Fortran and Python, something we are all born with but which most of us lose along with our baby teeth.

Put another way, there's no way you could know this unless you knew the right question to ask in the first place, which nobody does the first time they see weird, seemingly-inconsistent floating point behavior. Back when FORTRAN was still taught, this sort of problem was introduced pretty early in the curriculum because the language is intended for crunching numbers and the problems with mixed-type and mixed-precision arithmetic are serious and well known. You had to learn about these pitfalls quickly because it was the difference between getting believable answers and garbage.

Modern languages are designed to simplify the delivery of cat videos. No real computer scientist would be caught dead discussing floating point mathematics so you need to search [obscure backwater websites](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for information on how to make your numbers add up good and do other stuff good too. There is good info out there but again, you need to know what you're looking for in order to find it which most programmers don't when they hit this problem for the first time.

The short answer is to understand how computers simulate real numbers, how the languages you're using store those sorts of numbers, and ensure that the precision your application needs is supported by the data types you use. Hopefully that's more helpful than telling you to rephrase your question or RTFM.

And for what it's worth, I've been bitten by a similar problem recently where I had converted a code from single to double precision, forgetting that one of the binary files I was writing expected a single precision value. I only found this out during testing when visualization software choked on the broken binary file. The solution was obvious in hindsight; I reverted one variable back to single precision and all was well. The point is, even experienced people get tripped up by floating point. Barbie was right; math *is* hard...